# Why does my program repeat itself

Tags: python

Im attempting to create a game where you are given certain things to spot but when it generates new items it always repeats one and i am not sure why. so any solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
import random
cards=["3","helicopter","skip","chimmney","balloon","plane","bridge"]
while list is not []:
    card1=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove(card1)
    card2=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove (card2)
    print "card 1 = ",card1
    print "card 2 = ",card2
    choice=raw_input("type the card that you have found: ")
    if choice ==card1:
        card1=random.choice(cards)
        print "card 1 = ",card1
    else:
       card2=random.choice(cards)
       print "card 2 = ",card2
```

Comment: what is `list` do you mean `while cards` ?

Comment: **list** is a predefined type.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Change `while list is not []` to `while cards`. Note the former is checking if the builtin `list` is `[]` which is never the case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: In your `if` you select a new card, but don't remove it from `cards`. So you can get a repeat of that.

Comment: I don't understand why you select new cards in the `if` and `else`, since you're going to pick cards again when the loop repeats.

Comment: @T.C. : I hope you're getting the general problem here: we have very little idea what you're trying to do, let alone why you think your present output is wrong.  "It always repeats one" is unclear: repeats one *what*?  You print a card at the bottom of the loop, and then two cards at the top.  These are sometimes three different cards (i.e. no repetition).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your program causes an infinite loop because it works until the array is empty, but you never remove all objects from it.

```
import random
cards=["3","helicopter","skip","chimmney","balloon","plane","bridge"]
running = True
while running:
    card1=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove(card1)
    card2=random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove (card2)
    print "card 1 = ",card1
    print "card 2 = ",card2
    choice=raw_input("type the card that you have found: ")
    if choice ==card1:
        card1=random.choice(cards)
        print "card 1 = ",card1
        running = False
    else:
        card2=random.choice(cards)
        print "card 2 = ",card2
        running = False
```

Comment: `list is not []` always evaluates `True` so the loop never exits.

Comment: Why do you even use `while` at all here?

Comment: Thank you so much I understand now